# Why mysql_num_row less than condition doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

Why can't I get the echo right? `echo $tot` gives me 3

For some reason the $row variable will have a value greater than 3 `echo 'wrong'` at `if($row < $b)`

```
<?php 
    if($row < $b) {
        echo "good";
    } else { echo "wrong"; }

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM emp WHERE user='$login_session'"); // its currently zero
    $row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    $b = 3;
    $tot=$b - $row;
    echo $tot; 
?>
```

Comment: You're trying to use the variables $row and $b before you even define them. This is procedural, top to bottom execution.

Comment: stop using mysql as it is deprecated http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM emp WHERE user='$login_session'"); // its currently zero
$row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
$b = 3;
$tot=$b - $row;
echo "$tot"; 

if($row < $b) {
echo "good";
} else { echo "wrong"; }
?>
```

You have been trying to output variables, which is not defined.

You code was:

```
Ouput undefined variables
Assign something to this variables
```

In my code order is:

```
Assign something to this variables
Ouput undefined variables
```

Comment: thank u, i missed that sorry, for the dumb question.